# How to reduce rows by criteria to a single row in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe of Memos such that each memo has an id and an associated credit and debit amounts, coming from a getData call (in Scala) :

```
val memoData: Dataset[Row] = getData()
```

| memo_id | amount | credit_or_debit | date | memo_attr_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MEM_1 | 100 | D | 2023-06-01 | X |
| MEM_1 | 20 | C | 2023-06-07 | X |
| MEM_2 | 200 | D | 2023-06-01 | Y |
| MEM_2 | 50 | C | 2023-06-07 | Y |
| MEM_3 | 300 | D | 2023-06-01 | Z |

I would like to prepare a new dataframe with *just one row for each unique memo*, adjusting the credit and debits to a final amount. Also need to alias the rows to a new name (such as `memo_id` should be called `memo_number`), preserving some attributes of original memo:

```
val computedData = compute(memoData)
```

| memo_number | computed_amount | credit_or_debit | memo_attr_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MEM_1 | 80 | D | X |
| MEM_2 | 150 | D | Y |
| MEM_3 | 300 | D | Z |

Would like to understand how to do this with Spark apis ?
Any help would be appreciated.

I was thinking to register a temp table view and do it via SQL, going over each unique memo:

```
view = data.createOrReplaceTempView(TABLE_ALIAS)

memos = data.select("memo_id").distinct().collect().toList

for (memo <- memos) {
   val adjustedRow = sparkSession.sql(s"SELECT ....")
}
```

however, finding difficulty in creating adjusted row as we need to preserve some original attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some grouping by and aggregation should do the job. Example:

```scala
val data = Seq(
  ("MEM_1", 100, "D", "2023-06-01", "X"),
  ("MEM_1", 20, "C", "2023-06-07", "X"),
  ("MEM_2", 200, "D", "2023-06-01", "Y"),
  ("MEM_2", 50, "C", "2023-06-07", "Y"),
  ("MEM_3", 300, "D", "2023-06-01", "Z")
).toDF("memo_id", "amount", "credit_or_debit", "date", "memo_attr_1")

val computedData = data.withColumn(
    "amount",
    when(col("credit_or_debit") === "C", col("amount") * -1).otherwise(col("amount"))
  ).groupBy(
    col("memo_id").as("memo_number")
  ).agg(
    sum("amount").as("computed_amount"),
    Seq("memo_attr_1").map(c => first(c).as(c)):_*
  ).withColumn(
    "credit_or_debit", 
    when(col("computed_amount") >= 0, "D").otherwise("C")
  )

computedData.show()

//+-----------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
//|memo_number|computed_amount|credit_or_debit|memo_attr_1|
//+-----------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
//|      MEM_1|             80|              D|          X|
//|      MEM_2|            150|              D|          Y|
//|      MEM_3|            300|              D|          Z|
//+-----------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
```

This picks the first attribute value for each `memo_id` group. I you want to get all the attributes, then replace `first` with `collect_set` function for example.

Comment: This is helpful. Can you explain how the `.agg(... )` part will work ? Since different attributes (memo_attr_1 , memo_attr_2...) are same for each row of memo_id, do we need to list them separately with `first("memo_attr_1").as("memo_attr_1"), first("memo_attr_2").as("memo_attr_2")` ... and so on ?

Comment: @saurabh.kg001 you could use a map on sequence like this: `Seq("memo_attr_1", ..., "memo_attr_n").map(c => first(c).as(c)):_*`... please see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

With Memo defined at the top level (it cannot be in an object or class or trait etc.):

```scala
case class Memo(memo_id: String, amount: Int, credit_or_debit: String, date: Date, memo_attr_1: String)

def date(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int): Date = Date.valueOf(s"$year-$month-$day")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sum, collect_set}
import sparkSession.implicits._

def getData(): Dataset[Row] =
  Seq(
    Memo("MEM_1", 100, "D", date(2023, 6, 1),"X"),
    Memo("MEM_1", 20, "C", date(2023, 6, 7), "X"),
    Memo("MEM_2", 200, "D", date(2023, 6, 1), "Y"),
    Memo("MEM_2", 50, "C", date(2023, 6, 7) , "Y"),
    Memo("MEM_3", 300, "D", date(2023, 6, 1), "Z")
  ).toDS().toDF()

val memoData = getData()

def computeData(dataFrame: DataFrame): DataFrame =
  // make debits negative so they can be summed
  dataFrame.selectExpr("memo_id", "memo_attr_1", "if(credit_or_debit = 'D', amount * -1, amount) amount_for_sum" )
    // group by memo_id then sum whilst keeping the memo_attr_1's
    .groupBy("memo_id").agg(sum("amount_for_sum").as("summed_amount"), collect_set("memo_attr_1").as("memo_attr_1"))
    // renaming columns and making debit's show as positive and D
    .selectExpr("memo_id memo_number", "if(summed_amount < 0, summed_amount * -1, summed_amount) computed_amount", "if(summed_amount < 0, 'D', 'C') credit_or_debit", "memo_attr_1")

val computedData = computeData(memoData)

computedData.show()
```

yields:

```
+-----------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
|memo_number|computed_amount|credit_or_debit|memo_attr_1|
+-----------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
|      MEM_1|             80|              D|        [X]|
|      MEM_2|            150|              D|        [Y]|
|      MEM_3|            300|              D|        [Z]|
+-----------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
```

I assume memo_attr_1 can be different so it's a collected set to keep them all.

Please note that your original idea would generate new dataframes for each row, you want to keep transformations in the same dataset if possible and let spark do the transformations in one go.

You can keep the original fields for all matching memo rows by using collect_set (or list) against a struct with each field in it if that's useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While I am understanding aggregation, I am learning how selectExpr works. I found `withColumn` to be simpler, however would explore selectExpr, and this can also be a good alternate.